# How to upload albums to Google+ from an iphone app

Tags: iphone, google-plus

Could you please tell me how to upload an album from my iPhone app to Google+?
I was searching in Google and there is one app called Piconhand, but i want to upload a whole album from my app. Could you please tell me the Google server parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Google+ doesn't have a public photo API. Your best option is going to be the [Picasa Web API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html).